# Is there a way to script a scheduled update based on a saved search?

Tags: search, field, netsuite, suitescript, saved-searches

Having difficulty working out how to store a Saved Search result in a Custom Vendor Field.

I have a Saved Search that can provide the value (a count of all purchase transactions under a Vendor for the last year, divided by 365) but obviously it isn't stored.
I'm pretty certain you can run an existing Saved Search in a Script, but don't have a clue how to reference the Result of Search that already gives a summarized formula, filtered by the internal id of the Vendor.

Could anyone point me in the direction of the basic code needed? I'm hoping the script can just run the search, and SetFieldValue to the result?
(Keeping in mind I'm doing this to all Vendor records, not just one)

Comment: Just looping with  search result get the search value and set that value

Comment: Ok Praveen Kumar, that sounds logical - if I'm scheduling it to run on all Vendor records, how do I reference Vendor Internal ID? just that I'll need it for the search filter.

Comment: You have to get vendor id from saved search result because that  search result grouped by vendor, If my understanding is wrong pls elaborate your case.

Comment: thanks Praveen Kumar, I think I'm getting somewhere now, thanks. I'll have to look into this error - "entry point scripts must implement one script type function." - because I'm unable to upload the script, and I don't really know what I'm doing with Scheduled Scripts

Answer (score 0):

If the field only needs to be available on viewing the  vendor you can source a non-saved custom field's value from a saved search. Your search needs to include the record type as a filter. The search should resolve to a single column per vendor.

Then when you set up the custom field you select the search on the Validation &Defaulting tab

Comment: Hello bknights, thanks for your suggestion, but we do have this when necessary - just that I have 3 different instances of fields referenced from Saved Searches that need the value stored for other searches, etc.